# Is string_split() injection safe?

Tags: sql, sql-server, security

After reading [this great article](https://www.sommarskog.se/dyn-search.html) on handling multi-valued parameters, I learned about the convenient `string_split()` function.
I would like to use it in a where clause of a parameterized query like this:

```
WHERE [SomeTable].[SomeColumn] IN (
    SELECT TRIM(value)
    FROM string_split(@commaSeparatedListOfValues, ',')
)
```

Where `@commaSeparatedListOfValues` is a string received from user input and passed as a parameter.
I am wondering if the function is safe against injections. Is it really impossible to escape a string passed this way? What if the user provides a string like (naively)

`"firstValue , ');PRINT 'Hello'-- , thirdValue"`.

Of course it is added as a parameter in the first step and can do no harm, but does this still apply after splitting it?

I know `string_split()` can only return tables of string types. I find little to no mention of such issues, so I guess it is a non issue?

Comment: Why would you pass a comma separated list of values instead of using a table valued parameter?

Comment: There is risk of injection whenever a query is constructed from text that can vary at runtime. In T-SQL there is no risk of ever doing this accidentally, because it always involves `EXEC` or `sp_executesql`. In client code the problem is much more pernicious because there typically is no "native" way of representing queries, so strings are always used.

Comment: Hi, because I haven't gotten all the way through [link](https://www.sommarskog.se/arrays-in-sql.html) yet, I suppose.

Comment: For completeness I should add `OPENROWSET` and `OPENQUERY` to the cases in T-SQL where queries are built from strings. I think that's all of them, but in case I have forgotten anything the point remains that it's impossible to overlook when strings are being used to represent queries, and where this is not the case there is no risk of injection, regardless of what functions are employed.

Comment: No, sql cannot be injected in this scenario as there is no dynamically constructed and executed query; If your varchar column you were comparing to the split string values legitimately contained the string value as above (ignoring it would have been split on the comma in your passed value) you'd expect to be able to equate to it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no outright injection issue in the sense that arbitrary code cannot be executed. This is because, ultimately, `@commaSeparatedListOfValues` remains a string, and is never parsed into actual code.

The only injection issue is if you are  explicitly passing say three value, and one of them contained a comma.

For example, if you had a web page accepting a list of items, and the user entered `first` `sec,ond` `third`. If you mash these together with `,` then your SQL code will end up interpreting this as four separate values `first` `sec` `ond` `third`.

For this and other performance and correctness reasons, it's probably better to just use a Table Valued Parameter.